# how to export large sql file to phpmyadmin in kali linux?

Tags: magento2, xampp, linux

Hi i know in windows for exporting large sql files to phpmyadmin i run following command:

> mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] >
>   dumpfilename.sql

```
in location (C:\xampp\mysql\bin)
```

i have another `virtual Kali Linux system` in which Xampp directory is

> (opt/lampp)

but in mysql directory there is no bin folder , what's the accurate command and executable directory to run export sql command in kali linux .

---

note:(This question is related with magento 2 because i want to export its big sql file to local server so please if you can't answer it , dont mark it as irrelevant , i am so thankful to you :) ...  )

Answer (score 2):

It's so simple. You can export the database to any directory which you want.

To do so:

- Open terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and put the following command first:

**`cd /opt/lampp`**

- Now run the mysqldump command from here:

**`mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`**

This will export the database to **`/opt/lampp`** directory. You can change the path **`/opt/lampp`** to any other path.

Comment: i am getting this error : when trying to use this command :             mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!